# Converting PHP function to Java

Tags: java, php, function, email

I've been trying to convert a PHP code to Java, but its not working as intended. I get an error in the loop with "String index out of range" after a few runs on `char nextchar = inprogresskey.charAt(ranpos);`

The PHP code is:

```
function munge($address)
    {
        $address = strtolower($address);
        $coded = "";
        $unmixedkey = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.@";
        $inprogresskey = $unmixedkey;
        $mixedkey="";
        $unshuffled = strlen($unmixedkey);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($unmixedkey); $i++)
        {
            $ranpos = rand(0,$unshuffled-1);
            $nextchar = $inprogresskey{$ranpos};
            $mixedkey .= $nextchar;
            $before = substr($inprogresskey,0,$ranpos);
            $after = substr($inprogresskey,$ranpos+1,$unshuffled-($ranpos+1));
            $inprogresskey = $before.''.$after;
            $unshuffled -= 1;
        }
        $cipher = $mixedkey;

        $shift = strlen($address);

        for ($j=0; $j<strlen($address); $j++)
        {
            if (strpos($cipher,$address{$j}) == -1 )
            {
                    $chr = $address{$j};
                    $coded .= $address{$j};
            }
            else
            {
                    $chr = (strpos($cipher,$address{$j}) + $shift) % strlen($cipher);
                    $coded .= $cipher{$chr};
            }
        }

        $txt = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">\n";
        $txt .= "\ncoded = \"" . $coded . "\"\n" .
            "  key = \"".$cipher."\"\n".
            "  shift=coded.length\n".
            "  link=\"\"\n".
            "  for (i=0; i<coded.length; i++) {\n" .
            "    if (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))==-1) {\n" .
            "      ltr = coded.charAt(i)\n" .
            "      link += (ltr)\n" .
            "    }\n" .
            "    else {     \n".
            "      ltr = (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))-
    shift+key.length) % key.length\n".
            "      link += (key.charAt(ltr))\n".
            "    }\n".
            "  }\n".
            "document.write(\"<a href='mailto:\"+link+\"'>\"+link+\"</a>\")\n" .
            "\n".
            "//-"."->\n" .
            "<" . "/script><noscript>N/A" .
            "<"."/noscript>";
        return $txt;
    }
```

And my Java code is:

```
private String encryptEmail(String email)
    {
        String address = email.toLowerCase();
        String coded = "";
        String unmixedkey = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.@";
        String inprogresskey = unmixedkey;
        String mixedkey = "";
        int unshuffled = unmixedkey.length();

        for (int i = 0; i <= unmixedkey.length(); i++) {
           Random random = new Random();
           int ranpos = random.nextInt(unshuffled - 1);

           char nextchar = inprogresskey.charAt(ranpos);
           mixedkey += nextchar;

           String before = StringUtils.substring(inprogresskey, 0, ranpos);
           String after = StringUtils.substring(inprogresskey, ranpos + 1, unshuffled - (ranpos + 1));
           inprogresskey = before + "" + after;
           unshuffled -= 1;
        }

        String cipher = mixedkey;
        int shift = address.length();

        for (int j = 0; j < address.length(); j++) {
            int chr = -1;
            if (StringUtils.indexOf(cipher, address.substring(j - 1, j)) == -1) {
                coded += address.charAt(j);
            } else {
                chr = (cipher.charAt(j + shift)) % cipher.length();
                coded += cipher.charAt(chr);
            }
       }

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n");
       sb.append("var coded = \"" + coded + "\";\n");
       sb.append("var key = \"" + cipher + "\";\n");
       sb.append("var shift = coded.length;\n");
       sb.append("var link = \"\";\n");
       sb.append("for (i = 0; i < coded.length; i++) {\n");
       sb.append("  if (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))==-1) {\n");
       sb.append("      ltr = coded.charAt(i);\n");
       sb.append("      link += (ltr);\n");
       sb.append("  }\n");
       sb.append("  else {\n");
       sb.append("      ltr = (key.indexOf(coded.charAt(i))-shift+key.length) % key.length;\n");
       sb.append("      link += (key.charAt(ltr));\n");
       sb.append("  }");
       sb.append("}");
       sb.append("document.write(\"<a rel='nofollow' href='mailto:\" + link + \"'>\" + link + \"</a>\");\n");
       sb.append("</script>");

       return sb.toString();
    }
```

Am I missing out on some functions (charAt, indexOf)?

Thanks

Comment: You could post it to code review, I think it would be more indicated... (http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Code Review is for working code that needs cleaning up / refactoring / etc.  If the code doesn't work yet, it's off topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int ranpos = random.nextInt(unshuffled - 1);

atlast `ranpos = 1`

and you are doing `nextInt(1 - 1)`

```
char nextchar = inprogresskey.charAt(ranpos)
```

that's way above line gives you error

what you need to do is:

update your for loop  `for (int i = 0; i < unmixedkey.length(); i++)`

and inside the loop add the below line of code

```
    if(unshuffled==1)
      {
          ranpos = 1;
      }     
    else {
         ranpos = random.nextInt(unshuffled - 1);
        }
```

The below is fully functional for loop code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < unmixedkey.length(); i++) {
           Random random = new Random();
           int ranpos=0;
           if(unshuffled==1)
           {
               ranpos = 1;
           }else{
               ranpos = random.nextInt(unshuffled - 1);
           }
           char nextchar = inprogresskey.charAt(ranpos);
           mixedkey += nextchar;
           String before = StringUtils.substring(inprogresskey, 0, ranpos);
           String after = StringUtils.substring(inprogresskey, ranpos + 1, unshuffled - (ranpos + 1));
           inprogresskey = before + "" + after;
           unshuffled -= 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `unshuffled` is equal to `0` on the last time through the loop, and so `charAt(-1)` is failing.

You should take a look at Java IDEs like Eclipse and the debugger. Adding breakpoints will enable you to step through the code as it runs, and see the values of all variables, which would be the quickest way of solving this sort of issue in future.